# NMEA sentences - PGLOR, GNGSA and QZGSA

Tags: android, gps, nmea

I'm writing an Android app that reads and parses NMEA sentences from GPS receiver and using a Nexus S phone for tests.
I'm getting GPGGA, GPGSV, GPGSA and GPRMC sentences that are pretty common and very well documented, but in addition, I'm getting next sentences and I'cant find any info about them:
`PGLOR, GNGSA, QZGSA`
Where I can find some docs about those sentences format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $GN-prefix is usually used when the sentence is formed using several satellite constellations (so far usually Glonass and GPS are the viable options). The $QZ-prefix is a little more unclear but I assume that it is for the Japanese QZSS-satellite constellation.

The rest of the sentence after the prefix is standard NMEA 0183 and contains what the normal GSA-sentence would contain.

The $PGLOR is probably used to produce information and / or configure the locationing chip. Or something similarly uninteresting.

What's really interesting is that Nexus S seems to have a Multi GNSS locationing chip.

Further information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation)

Comment: I'd like to add a link to [the best NMEA related site there is](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) in my opinion. Well written and informative. Also for the OP, most people will generally be happy with the Recommended Minimum Data for GPS sentence(the $GPRMC). The multi constellation devices simply change the prefix a little, but the data follows the standard.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote an app that parsed the GPGGA NMEA strings, my advice is parse what you need, and leave the rest. Generally you don't need all formats, only specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

The first two characters typically define the type of device sending the message, with the last three being the type of message.  `$GNGSA` and `$QZGSA` should be reporting the same or similar data as `$GPGSA`, which would be satellite data, including dilution of precision.

I don't know which device these come from, but `GN` is mentioned here: http://macrogroup.ru/content/data/store/images/f_1072_5353_1.pdf

Regarding `$PGLOR`... I'm not sure.  Perhaps if you could post what chipset is used internally, its documentation could be consulted.